# select2 disable results in infinite scrolling customAdapter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I've tried to modify the custom adapter implementing the infinite scrolling (no ajax) in order to show disabled results but it's not working. Basically I've added the property 'disabled' to the object list and tried to use it in the custom adapter with no luck.

Any advice?

```
$.fn.select2.amd.define('select2/data/customAdapter', [ 'select2/data/array', 'select2/utils' ], function(ArrayData, Utils) {
function CustomDataAdapter($element, options) {
    CustomDataAdapter.__super__.constructor.call(this, $element, options);
}

Utils.Extend(CustomDataAdapter, ArrayData);

CustomDataAdapter.prototype.current = function(callback) {

    var found = [], findValue = null, initialValue = this.options.options.initialValue, selectedValue = this.$element.val(), jsonData = this.options.options.jsonData, jsonMap = this.options.options.jsonMap;

    if (initialValue !== null) {
        findValue = initialValue;
        this.options.options.initialValue = null;
    } else if (selectedValue !== null) {
        findValue = selectedValue;
    }

    if (!this.$element.prop('multiple')) {
        findValue = [ findValue ];
        this.$element.html();
    }

    for (var v = 0; v < findValue.length; v++) {
        for (var i = 0, len = jsonData.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (findValue[v] == jsonData[i][jsonMap.id]) {
                found.push({
                    id : jsonData[i][jsonMap.id],
                    text : jsonData[i][jsonMap.text],
                    disabled : jsonData[i][jsonMap.disabled]
                });
                if (this.$element.find("option[value='" + findValue[v] + "']").length == 0) {
                    var $option = $("<option></option>");
                    $option.val(jsonData[i][jsonMap.id]);
                    $option.text(jsonData[i][jsonMap.text]);
                    if (jsonData[i][jsonMap.disabled]) {
                        $option.attr("disabled", "disabled");
                    }
                    this.$element.append($option);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    this.$element.find("option").prop("selected", false).removeAttr("selected");
    for (var v = 0; v < found.length; v++) {
        this.$element.find("option[value='" + found[v].id + "']").prop("selected", true).attr("selected", "selected");
    }

    if (!found.length && !this.$element.prop('multiple')) {
        found.push({
            id : jsonData[0][jsonMap.id],
            text : jsonData[0][jsonMap.text],
            disabled : jsonData[0][jsonMap.disabled]
        });
        this.$element.html(new Option(jsonData[0][jsonMap.text], jsonData[0][jsonMap.id], true, true));
    }

    callback(found);
};

CustomDataAdapter.prototype.query = function(params, callback) {
    if (!("page" in params)) {
        params.page = 1;
    }

    var jsonData = this.options.options.jsonData, pageSize = this.options.options.pageSize, jsonMap = this.options.options.jsonMap;

    var results = $.map(jsonData, function(obj) {
        if (new RegExp(params.term, "i").test(obj[jsonMap.text])) {
            return {
                id : obj[jsonMap.id],
                text : obj[jsonMap.text],
                disabled : obj[jsonMap.disabled]
            };
        }
    });

    callback({
        results : results.slice((params.page - 1) * pageSize, params.page * pageSize),
        pagination : {
            more : results.length >= params.page * pageSize
        }
    });
};

return CustomDataAdapter;

});
var jsonAdapter = $.fn.select2.amd.require('select2/data/customAdapter');
```